# Oracle SQL — Grouping aggregate function with analytic functions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have SQL like this:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'YYYY') AS year,
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'MM') AS month,      
  name,
  SUM(reste) OVER (PARTITION BY name, ad_org_id) AS tot_reste_client,
  nameregion AS region
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'YYYY'),
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'MM'),      
  name,
  nameregion
ORDER BY name;
```

I get tried to put it in the GROUP BY clause and i get error like this "Is not group function",tried using HAVING and it tell me "window  functions are not allowed here".

Couldn't find solution?, i'm using Oracle 12.

Comment: Use a subquery, SUM(reste) OVER (PARTITION BY name, ad_org_id) FROM t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions are calculated *after* GROUP BY/HAVING, so usually you can add aggregation to `reste`:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'YYYY') AS year,
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'MM') AS month,      
  name,
  SUM(SUM(reste)) OVER (PARTITION BY name, ad_org_id) AS tot_reste_client,
  nameregion AS region
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'YYYY'),
  TO_CHAR(dateinvoiced, 'MM'),      
  name,
  nameregion
ORDER BY name;
```

But this should also fail due to `ad_org_id`, which is not in GROUP BY, maybe you can use a `MIN(ad_org_id)`.

Comment: Still giving the same error "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @IsmailSensei: If you use `MIN(ad_org_id)` (or add `ad_org_id`to GROUP BY) there will be no error, but I don't know if this is what you want.

Comment: The problem is that i forgot about ad_org_id, i did't use MIN i just added ad_org_id to the GROUP BY. Thanks.